# ionic Youtube player autoplay not working on device

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

How to autoplay and automatic fullscreen mode of my youtube videos on ionic build. by the way it’s working on ionic serve -l

See screenshot.
[image: sample image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this it add autoplay=1 at end

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/JW5meKfy3fY?autoplay=1
```

Comment: I already did that.
here's my url https://www.youtube.com/embed/9yZEvkofi24?rel=0;&autoplay=1
but still it's working only in ionic serve not in ionic build

Comment: call this url dynamically store that in database & call it will solve your problem

Comment: Why do I need to store it in database? Here's my sample array  videos: any[] = [
    {
      title: 'flashligh application',
      video: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/9yZEvkofi24?rel=0;&autoplay=1',
    }
  ]

and it's working only in ionic serve not in ionic build/device

Comment: can you provide an snippet of the code so we could help you better?